# Sorting array in alphabetical order in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a set of data in DB and I am sending it to my Android App using an API function.

I have written this in PHP.

I want to sort JSON array in alphabetical order and then send it in JSON array format.

Here is the code I have, I am not sure how or where to sort this out?

```
        $response["categorydetails"] = array();
      
        while ($categoryrow = mysqli_fetch_array($categorylist))
        {
            // temp user array
            $categorydetail = array();
            $categorydetail["sno"] = $categoryrow["sno"];
            $categorydetail["category"] = $categoryrow["category"];     
          
            // push single product into final response array
            array_push($response["categorydetails"], $categorydetail);
        }

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login Successful";


        echo json_encode($response);
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: By which column you want to sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're getting the data from a database, it would make most sense to sort the data using an `ORDER BY` clause in the SQL query. This will be much more efficient than trying to sort it in PHP.

I don't know your real query or table name, but this is the general idea:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable ORDER BY someColumn
```

You didn't say which column you want to sort by, but I'd guess it's the `category`? In that case, `ORDER BY category` would be what you need to add to your SQL.

Documentation: [MySQL Reference Manual - Sorting Rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html)